# Counting methods in project

Tags: java, android, shell, methods, dex

I ran into the 65000 method limit on my android project and I'm trying to use this [script](https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/6056422) to count my methods, which uses some extra jars. I keep getting errors when i run the script, so my guess is the jars are not included properly or I'm missing some extra step. Anybody dealt with this before?

EDIT:

```
cat build/dex/debug/classes.dex | head -c 92 | tail -c 4 | hexdump -e '1/4 "%d\n"'
```

you can use this code to count.

Comment: That's a lot of methods.

Comment: IKR :P it's mostly the 3rd party libs that I'm using

Comment: I saw the post and already shrunk it. my question is how to use that script to count the methods, not how to shrunk. Unless you can use that to count the methods.

Comment: Don't add an answer to your question in the question. If you want to add an answer, actually add it as an answer. In this case, the question should probably just be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: What errors do you experience when running the script? Please add more details to your question.